# What's wrong with my injection-provider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following, the config works, but the run returns

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AngularyticsConsoleHandlerProvider <- AngularyticsConsoleHandler <- Angularytics
```

Code:

```
angular.module('weather', ['ngRoute', 'angularytics']).
config(function(AngularyticsProvider){

    AngularyticsProvider.setEventHandlers(['Console', 'GoogleUniversal']);
}).run(function(Angularytics){
    Angularytics.init();
}).
controller(....
```

Why?

this is how I load the reference, in the html-head:

```
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angularytics/src/angularytics.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you loading a reference to Angularytics somewhere

Comment: Is it a spelling error? Looks like the module injection should have 'A' instead of 'a' for Angularytics?

Answer (score 0):

From the project page (https://github.com/mgonto/angularytics) it looks like your code should be `AngularyticsProvider` not `$AngularyticsProvider`

Comment: thanks, that's not it though(the $ slipped in when I removed some other stuff from config that wasn't needed to reproduce the error.)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had missed a few javascript-files that were requierd.